# error when connecting DX100 controller

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, motoman, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to connect with DX100 controller via Ethernet. I have completed all step according to tutorial.

But when I am launching `roslaunch motoman_driver robot_interface_streaming_dx100.launch robot_ip:=10.20.30.10` according to this,
http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/Usage#Robot_Controller
I am getting this error,

```
 /robot_ip_address: 10.20.30.10
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /
    joint_state (motoman_driver/robot_state)
    joint_trajectory_action (industrial_robot_client/joint_trajectory_action)
    motion_streaming_interface (motoman_driver/motion_streaming_interface)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [16267]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 7ff70826-3a94-11e9-a310-e094677543f1
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [16280]
started core service [/rosout]
process[joint_state-2]: started with pid [16288]
process[motion_streaming_interface-3]: started with pid [16298]
process[joint_trajectory_action-4]: started with pid [16305]
[ERROR] [1551274510.017293580]: Failed to find topic_list parameter
[ERROR] [1551274510.019096560]: Cannot find user-specified joint names. Tried ROS parameter 'controller_joint_names' and the URDF in 'robot_description'.
[ERROR] [1551274510.019235316]: Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection refused' (errno: 111)
[ERROR] [1551274510.025299639]: Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection refused' (errno: 111)
[ERROR] [1551274510.025411427]: Failed to receive message length
[ERROR] [1551274510.025449442]: Failed to receive incoming message
[ERROR] [1551274510.029772460]: Failed to find topic_list parameter
[ERROR] [1551274510.032185826]: Cannot find user-specified joint names. Tried ROS parameter 'controller_joint_names' and the URDF in 'robot_description'.
[ERROR] [1551274510.032383954]: Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection refused' (errno: 111)
[ERROR] [1551274510.036218270]: Cannot find user-specified joint names. Tried ROS parameter 'controller_joint_names' and the URDF in 'robot_description'.
[ERROR] [1551274510.037383101]: Failed to initialize joint_names.
[ERROR] [1551274510.057214554]: Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection refused' (errno: 111)
[ERROR] [1551274510.307608223]: Timeout connecting to robot controller.  Send new motion command to retry.
[ERROR] [1551274515.026198348]: Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection refused' (errno: 111)
[ERROR] [1551274515.026460781]: Failed to receive message length
[ERROR] [1551274515.026616096]: Failed to receive incoming message
[ERROR] [1551274520.027295751]: Failed to connect to server, rc: -1. Error: 'Connection refused' (errno: 111)
```

It is written in tutorial,
Make sure the ROS trajectory node has been enabled by invoking the robot_enable service.

I can enable it by rosservice call.

But how can I enable it before launching above (roslaunch motoman_driver robot_interface_streaming_dx100.launch robot_ip:=10.20.30.10) command.

When I am starting controller in teach pendent I get Alarm like,

```
MotoROS: Controller cfg invalid
  [102]
```

But when I reset this alarm, it goes. is this a problem?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316873/error-when-connecting-dx100-controller/) by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2019-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When I am starting controller in teach pendent I get Alarm like,

> ```
> MotoROS: Controller cfg invalid
> ```

```
  [102]
```

> But when I reset this alarm, it goes. is this a problem?

yes, this is a problem. From the [Troubleshooting section on error 8003](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Troubleshooting#Alarm:_8003.5B100_-_111.5D):

> Your robot controller requires internal configuration changes to support the MotoROS driver.

> For DX100: Please contact your local Yaskawa Motoman office to order the MotoROS runtime. In North/South America, the part number for this configuration is `180014-1`. In Europe, the part number for this configuration is `171403`.

Did you order the runtime license as was clarified in #q316165?

If so, I believe Yaskawa should also have updated your controller configuration with the necessary parameters to be able to run MotoROS on your DX100. If that hasn't happened -- or wasn't done correctly -- I believe you can run into errors such as the one you show.

As is stated under the *Requirements - MotoPlus Runtime License* [section](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver#Requirements) (emphasis mine):

> The MotoROS application and source is available for public download. However, ordering this part number will ensure your controller is updated with correct system software, the MotoROS driver is installed, **and all internal parameters are properly configured.**

Can you confirm you've had your controller configuration updated for MotoROS?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-27**:
@millete: FYI.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-02-27**:
I will contact them and update it here.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-27**:
So just to be clear: you haven't yet received/purchased the runtime license, or the parameter update wasn't done (correctly)?

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-02-27**:
haven't purchased license.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-27**:
That would definitely be a problem then -- as I also wrote in #q316165.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-02-27**:
is there any problem with **robot_enable** service call after I launch roslaunch motoman_driver robot_interface_streaming_dx100.launch robot_ip:=10.20.30.10 ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-28**:
I don't see any output in the log messages that you posted that is unexpected, given that MotoROS is just not running on your controller.

Diagnosing any of those errors right now is not very productive, as they're most likely caused by the `8000` error.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-04-24**:
@gvdhoorn after updating controller with ALL.PRM file, which was from yaskawa. there is still alarm coming when starting controller, MotoROS config invalid [105]. what can be the problem now?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-24**:
If the error is:

> ```
> ALARM 8003
> ```

```
  MotoROS: Controller cfg invalid
 [105]
```

then it would appear your controller still hasn't been properly setup for MotoROS.

`105` is one of the possible values that the "parameter validation" code in MotoROS returns. According to [this](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/blob/7de25115d7a081bf285db98972ab311c23660b65/motoman_driver/MotoPlus/Controller.c#L148-L154), there is a chance that the MotoPlus runtime hasn't been enabled.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-04-24**:
yes error is [105].

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-04-24**:
but they have updated controller configuration. may be I have to contact them again.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-24**:
Did they enable MotoPlus runtime for you? DId you have to pay?

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-04-24**:
I think that's i have to ask what is missing.

**Comment by [millete](https://answers.ros.org/users/28748/millete/) on 2019-04-24**:
@nd You are indeed missing a one or more of the protected parameter settings. I have sent a message to the Yaskawa support team in Germany to notify them of this issue. Please contact the support team to have them fix your ALL.PRM file. TCS@yaskawa.eu.com

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-04-24**:
@millete thank you for the help. I have sent mail to yaskawa support.

**Comment by [nd](https://answers.ros.org/users/32578/nd/) on 2019-04-26**:
@millete @gvdhoorn thanks. after getting new modified file this error is gone.